# Alternative to skip locked in mariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, message-queue

Is there any good & performant alternative to `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` in mariaDB? Or is there any good practice to archieve job queueing in mariaDB?

Comment: "Don't queue it, just do it".

Comment: The problem is that in my project the user has to wait several seconds until all mails sended...

Comment: …are you kidding?

Comment: Sorry.  Can you elaborate on what the processing does, and why a queue is useful.  Also are you running on Linux, where it is easy to simply launch separate processes in stead of queueing.

Comment: Users can create posts in groups and then mail notifications gets sended to all users attending this group. If i »…just do it« the users is paused for several seconds when submitting the post. Not acceptable imo. Tested a queue with »skip locked«, worked fine, but sadly were working with mariaDB, not supporting it.

Comment: The only way to implement a queue in MySQL without fretting about lock contention is for the queue to be consumed by only one job processor. Don't try to have multiple consumers lock records in MySQL. The job processor reads the next item from the database, then invokes workers to do the work asynchronously.

Comment: If you don't like that solution, then use a real message queue like ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ or AWS SQS. When you create an entry in the database, push it into the queue. Then the readers pull from the queue instead of polling the database.

Comment: @Karl - If practical, use Bill's single-consumer solution.  If not and you want to stay in MySQL/MariaDB, then I like ysth's solution because it avoids holding locks for a long time.  Both avoid holding any lock for more than a fraction of a second; this is efficient, good, scalable, etc.  But it does require a little more code and/or imposes constraints on the overall system.

Comment: @BillKarwin I will try the single job processor - multi workers approach and will give feedback. Thank you!

Comment: `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` has been implemented and is being reviewed and may make it into mariadb 10.6: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13115.  There's a linked ticket for UPDATE as well, but it is less clear to me that people will work to get that in 10.6.

Comment: `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` will be in 10.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a lock to indicate a queue record is being processed, use an indexed `processing` column.  Set it to 0 for new records, and, in a separate transaction from any processing, select a single not yet processing record and update it to 1.  Possibly also store the time and process or thread id and server that is processing the record.  Have a separate monitoring process to detect jobs flagged as processing that did not complete processing within the expected time.

An alternative that avoids even the temporary lock on a non-primary index needed to select a record is to use a separate, non-database message queue to notify you of new records available in the database queue.  (Unless you won't ever care if a unit of work is processed more than once, I would always use a database table in addition to any non-database queue.)

Comment: currently looking into the gearman extension for php. But seems little bit hard to get it running in php 7.4.

Comment: Do you have a example for a »non-database message queue« for php?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html  or  https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib with any AMQP compatible queue

Answer (score 2):

DELETE FROM QUEUE_TABLE LIMIT 1 RETURNING *

for dequeue operations. Depending on your needs it might work ok

Comment: This is not MySQL

Comment: Yes, @marco . MariaDB can do some things MySQL can't.

Answer (score 2):

Update 2022-06-14:

[MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/) supports `SKIP LOCKED` now.